# In what levels is the Green Demon Challenge possible?

Tags: super-mario-64

I've seen some youtubers do that challenge where in SM64, you trigger a 1UP that follows you until it gave you the 1UP, and then try to take all 8 red coins and the star before it reaches you.

Most people do it in Bob-Bomb Battlefield, but is the challenge possible to do in other levels? If yes, which ones?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Green Demon Challenge](http://vgchallenge.wikia.com/wiki/Green_Demon_Challenge) wiki, there are a total of 9 different levels this challenge can be done on.

> The Green Demon Challenge is available in the following worlds
>
> 1. Bob-omb Battlefield
> 2. Whomp's Fortress
> 3. Cool, Cool, Mountain
> 4. Shifting Sand Land
> 5. Snowman's Land
> 6. Tick Tock Clock
> 7. Rainbow Ride
> 8. Bowser in the Fire Sea
> 9. Wing Mario Over the Rainbow

Comment: Where can this be done in Tick Tock Clock?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Unfortunately the wiki doesn't state where in each level, but [this Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_pG-LcJuVMA) video may help for Tick Tock Clock

Comment: Ive honestly never heard of this. Maybe I'm out of the loop but does completing this challenge do anything in game? Or is it a player-made bragging rights kind of thing?

Comment: @Dpeif Aside from the coin collection aspect, I don't think the rules in this challenge affects the game. Somebody who is more of an expect with Mario would be able to answer that more clearly. Challenges like this are generally player-made for bragging rights or to increase the difficulty. The part in this challenge that increases the difficulty is that the green 1UP mushroom is faster than Mario

Comment: @Dpeif its more of that kind of thing where youtubers will try and add a difficult challenge to an older game. So it does nothing in game, it's just for the sense of pride and accomplishment.